# Is there a google drive SDK mail list or RSS feed?

Tags: google-drive-api

Given Google drive is brand spanking new. I expect there will be lots of changes, more documentation, new code examples, changes in the API. Is there some sort of mailing list or ??? I can use to stay on top of these updates?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 2):

The Google Drive SDK has no mailing list.  All questions are handled on Stack Overflow, under the [google-drive-sdk tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk).

For updates about changes to the SDK, subscribe to the [Google Apps Developer Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/).  Our standard practice is to post about all updates there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't really a mailing list. However, Google does provide many sources for content related to Google Drive. Here is a list:

[**Google Blog** - Introducing Google Drive... yes, really](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/04/introducing-google-drive-yes-really.html)

[**Twitter** - @google](http://twitter.com/google)

[**Google Drive Product Forums** - Ask, Report, Share](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/drive)

[**Google Drive SDK** - Develop Application Support for Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/)

[**Google Drive Help** - Customer and Developer](https://support.google.com/drive/?hl=en&p=web_home)

Answer (score 0):

You could do what I did.

Just hover your mouse on the google-drive-sdk tag. You will see two options. Choose between email/RSS.

Attached is the image. 
http://goo.gl/bGV8h

Edit: Corrected the link